# swift: images in tableView

Tags: ios, swift

There are `TableViewController` and`ViewController`. I want to show the image in the cell `TableViewController`, provided that the track time in the`ViewController` is greater than 1.

I use this code to do it:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(format: "Cell%d", indexPath.row), for: indexPath)

    var timeString = 0
    if indexPath.row >= 0 {
        timeString = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "currentTime\(indexPath.row)")
    }
    let timeInSeconds = timeString    

    if timeInSeconds > 1 {

        //show image

    }
}
```

This code allows to show the image in the cell that was clicked. And after moving to `ViewController` and returning, the user will see the image in the cell.

But sometimes due to actions in the `ViewController` (if the track number changes) I need to show several image in several cells.

How to do it?

Comment: I can't understand your question. Can you please describe brief ?

Comment: I know exactly what your want to do.But i can't get your question.

Comment: @girish_pro If I listen track0, track1, track2 in `ViewController ` I want to show image in cell0, cell1, cell2 in `TableViewController `. Did you understand me?

Comment: @kaizippo If I listen track0, track1, track2 in ViewController I want to show image in cell0, cell1, cell2 in TableViewController . How to do it? This is my question.

Comment: Do not load data from `UserDefaults` in `cellForRow`. This method is called frequently. Get the integer values in `viewDidLoad` and put it in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Please do as folllow, I am sure it willl work for you.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(format: "Cell%d", indexPath.row), for: indexPath)

    var timeString = 0
    if indexPath.row >= 0 {
        timeString = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "currentTime\(indexPath.row)")
    }
    let timeInSeconds = timeString    

    if timeInSeconds > 1 {
        //show image
    }else{
       // Set your UIImageView to nil here...
       // imageView.image = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: If I listen track0, track1, track2 in `ViewController` I want to show image in cell0, cell1, cell2 in `TableViewController` . How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a bool variable.After listening to track0,track1,track2 make that bool variable as true and check if bool is true in cellForRowAt()  show images.

Comment: What if user listening to track0,track1,track2,track3?

Comment: make that bool variable false in viewDidLoad.so in  cellForRowAt method check  if bool == true -> show images else show whatever you want.

Comment: What if have 70 tracks?

Comment: What do you want do if listening to track and after completed listening?

Comment: I want to show image in table cell if user listen track. For example: today user listen track0, track1, track2 in `ViewController`. It means that in `TableViewController ` user will see 3 images in cell0, cell1, cell2. Tomorrow user listen user listen track3, track4, track5 in `ViewController`. It means that in `TableViewController ` user will see 6 images in cell3, cell4, cell5 + images in cell0, cell1, cell2(saved yesterday).

Comment: are you updating to server after completion of listening?

Comment: user2931321 no.

Comment: Okay.So you are maintaining an array to load tableview right. Add extra key "isListened" as bool make that boolean true or false based on listening condition.check this boolean in cellForRowAt method to display images.